# MS Access: How to update multiple values and query multiple tables (many to many relationships)?

Tags: database, ms-access, relational-database, ms-access-2013

Disclaimer: I've only started using Access last week for an internship, so please bear with me, I still don't really understand it or the theory behind it.

Having read and watched many tutorials online, I thought I was ready to start creating my database on MS Access, though I'm afraid I was wrong.

I was given an Excel file with over 75k rows to work with, but I have struggled with it, since most tutorials seem to explain fairly DBs where one usually populates the tables from scratch.

I have my main table, X, where my primary key is called NIF (meaning the Portuguese fiscal number), each number representing a unique company. Besides many other fields, I also have 5 columns called Banco_1, Banco_2, ..., to put it simply, each company can have an account in 5 different banks. I then created another table, Y, where I attributed a number to each different possible bank - Primary Key, an autonumber (Bank_ID).

Because I believed this to be a many to many relationship, I then thought I had to create a bridging table, Z, with its unique PK (also an autonumber), where one could find both the NIF and Y's PK as foreign keys. Thus, a specific NIF could be repeated up to 5 times if it had 5 different bank accounts.

I tried running a selection query with the tables, but for the life of me, it wouldn't work. NIFs would be repeated time and time again and there would be no value in the Bank_ID field, or it would be a completely random number. I'm sure I was doing everything wrong.

How can I create a table which basically works as my bridging table without having to manipulate the data in excel and import it to access? I'm sure there must be a way to connect this information and create the aforementioned third table, Z.

I would also like to know how is it possible to update several values at a time? Consider I didn't need a bridging table and wanted to simply create a relationship between table X and Y. How can I go about updating Banks' values (the banks' names) in table X to the Bank_ID I created in table Y? An update query is easy enough to do so if you only have 2 IDs, but with several?

I would like to finish this long "essay" by informing you that I'm not proficient whatsoever in coding, SQL and VBA included, so solutions featuring both might be trickier for me to perform.

Hope you can help me out! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though you are not getting the joins between your three tables right. It sounds like you are correctly normalising the 5 columns in excel into a bridging table. Ultimately you would have something like this (sqlserver syntax):

```
create table Company(CompanyID int, CompanyName varchar(100));
create table Bank(BankID int, BankName varchar(100));
create table Account(AccountID int, CompanyID int, BankID int, AccountNumber varchar(20));

select CompanyID, CompanyName, BankID, BankName, AccountNumber
from Company
join Account on Account.CompanyID=Company.CompanyID
join Bank on Bank.BankID=Account.BankID
```

I've left out the foreign keys but I think you can see where they would be.